# Installing scikit-image on Android

Tags: android, scikit-image

Can I run scikit-image on Android? Do I need a specific version of the OS? I haven't been able to find a doc or tutorial explaining its installation on the platform. The instructions [only mention Debian and Ubuntu](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html). Would I need to compile from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scikit-image is strictly a Python library, and Android runs on Java.

As an alternative, I would suggest JavaCV if you want something like scikit-image. It's a Java port of the OpenCV library, which is very similar to what you are looking for. https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

However, if you are intent on using scikit-image, you can try using Jython, although it may be buggy when used with Android. http://www.jython.org/

You can use Cygwin if you want to install with Linux commands on a Windows computer. https://www.cygwin.com/